# Modify the position of application customizer (Breadcrumb) SPFX

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I need to change the position of an application extension on my page. It sits at the top, I want to drop it lower. The Microsoft documentation I have seen just points me to the top or bottom region. Is it possible for me to access another region?

The [bread crumb](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-application-breadcrumb) code-based is on the official PnP GitHub samples.

Current Position:

[image: Current Position]

How I want to modify the position:

[image: Current Position]

Answer (score 1):

Currently Microsoft only supports two placeholders in application customizer:

- Top Placeholder
- Bottom Placeholder

**Documentation**: [Use page placeholders from Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions)

---

**Workaround**:

Instead of using default available placeholders to bind the breadcrumb navigation, you can access the specific DOM elements using selectors (id/class/attribute) & use those to bind the breadcrumb navigation.

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.